# Does this version of Clairaut-Schwarz theorem hold when mixed partial derivatives are of order greater than $2$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I usually encounter Clairaut-Schwarz theorem where the mixed partial derivatives are of order $2$, i.e.

> $\textbf{Clairaut-Schwarz Theorem:}$ Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$, $f:X \to F$, and $i, j \in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Suppose that $\partial_j \partial_i f$ is continuous at $a$ and that $\partial_j f$ exists in a neighborhood of $a$. Then $\partial_i \partial_j f (a)$ exists and $$\partial_i \partial_j f (a) = \partial_j \partial_i f (a)$$

I would like to ask if Clairaut-Schwarz theorem holds in case the mixed partial derivatives are of arbitrary order $m$, i.e.

> Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$, $f:X \to F$, and $m \in \mathbb N$. Suppose $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_m \in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1, \ldots, m\}$. If $\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f$ is continuous at $a$ and $\partial_{j_{\sigma(2)}}  \cdots \partial_{j_{\sigma(m)}} f$ exists in a neighborhood of $a$, then $$\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)= \partial_{j_{\sigma(1)}} \partial_{j_{\sigma(2)}}  \cdots \partial_{j_{\sigma(m)}} f(a)$$

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The Clairaut-Schwarz theorem holds in case the mixed partial derivatives are of arbitrary order  according to my vector calculus textbook.

Comment: Hi @JG123, is the hypothesis in your version different than in mine?

Comment: It seems to me that I'm unable to receive answer for this question on MSE, so I asked the same question on *mathoverflow.net* [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346161/does-this-version-of-clairaut-schwarz-theorem-hold-when-mixed-partial-derivative).